# How can I specify a level of a factor while in an lme?

Tags: r, mixed-model

I have a dataset with repeated measures at different speeds. I've binned the speed ranges into 0-0.5, 0.5-1.5, and 1.5-infinity.

```
mydata`$`fact<−cut(mydata$section, breaks=c(0,0.5,1.5,Inf))
```

which gives the levels (0,0.5]  (0.5,1.5]  (1.5,Inf]

I first used the lme to test all speeds together to see if x and y are speed-dependent. Now I want to isolate speed bins, but I want to do it in the model instead of re-defining the factor. I can't seem to get it to work. "Fact" is what the speed bins correspond to.

```
lme(y ~ x + factor(repeatedmeasures) + fact, random = ~1 | z, data=mydata, na.action=na.omit)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "isolate speed bins"? Do you mean that you want to fit a model for each bin?

Comment: Exactly. Apologies if I'm being naiive!

Comment: Why are you converting a continuous variable to discrete?  There are very few situations where this is appropriate.  It can very easily be manipulated to show spurious relationships.

Comment: Hadley, do you mean speed? It's biologically relevant to categorize the continuous variable into discrete bins. Between certain speeds there are locomotory gait transitions, so I am investigating each speed bin as to compare, say, walks with walks, rather than walks with runs.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to fit separate models for each level of your factor, then probably the easiest way is to use the `subset=` argument to `lme` (or any other GLM in R, btw). For example,

```
lme(y ~ x + factor(repeatedmeasures) + fact, 
    random = ~1 | z, data=mydata, subset=as.numeric(fact) == 1)
```

should subset on the first level of your factor. I used `as.numeric()` because you didn't provide labels to your newly created factor. To do so, you can fill the `labels=` argument when calling `cut()`, such that the above code could read

```
lme(..., subset=fact == "low")
```

for example (assuming the first level of `fact` is named `low`). In both cases, you can easy set up a loop (using something like `for i in 1:nlevels(fact)` or `for i in seq_along(levels(fact))`) to iterate over your different models.

Comment: Thanks, I would've never have tried that! I will give it a go.

Comment: Can this also be done for pairwise.t.test? The structure doesn't accept any subset command. I had to try a roundabout method of re-defining the variables to include only data from "low" speed but I'm not sure I believe the results from the t-test.

Comment: I was able to get around it by using 
i<-factor=="low"
pairwise.t.test(animals$feature[i], anotherfactor[i], p.adjust.method = "holm", pool.sd = TRUE, paired = FALSE, data=animals)

but if you have a better suggestion I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: @Alexis You can subset a data.frame at any time, for instance: `df <- data.frame(y=rnorm(20), g1=gl(2, 10, labels=letters[1:2]), g2=gl(5, 2, 20)); with(subset(df, g1=="a"), pairwise.t.test(y, g2))`.